# Problem with absolute value of function integral convergence

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

So, if we put $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ then we have the result as $\pi$, which is known from analysis. Consider, for some reason, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\frac{\sin(x)}{x}| dx$, wolfram will not tell you how much is this, and I think that this does not even converge(it is $+\infty$), but do not know how to show that.

In the case this is finite, please tell me how much is this latter integral. If this is not finite then I need all-correct solution to following problem: find $\lim_{a\to +\infty} f_a$ , in space $D'(\mathbb{R})$ (so, the space of distributions, and $f_a$ are the distributions which arise from functions $f_a = \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$, if $x\neq 0$ and $f_a(0) = a$, they are continuous, so they are in $L_1^{loc}(\mathbb{R})$  and so, they do arise distributions for all $a>0$. The above integral will show when you try to explain why you can put limit under integral sign using dominant convergence theorem. Thanks in advance.

Third thing, if you are successful in finding a limit in above paragraph, can someone think of an array of distributions that has no limit? If it can, please provide me with example and possible proof, and if it can not , provide me with theorem which states so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the absolute value to converge you need the positive part to converge and for this you can pick any subset the domain and bound the integral there. If I have time I'll write a solution for you but look at intervals where $\sin(x)$ is big and $x$ of the order of $n\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that on $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$
$$
\left|\,\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\right|\gt\frac{|\sin(x)|}{(k+1)\pi}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would never get to that argument, and still, it is simple

Answer (score 0):

Now that robjohn posted answer we know to prove $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\frac{\sin(x)}{x}| dx$ is $+\infty$, I need to solve correctly the problem named in second paragraph. I know the answer for third part right now:

Let $a>0$. Then, $e^{ax}$ is clearly infinite differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$. Now, a first  example of a distribution that looks like it is formed out from continuous function ,but it is not is $P\frac{1}{x} = v.p. \int{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}$ and now, $e^{ax}P\frac{1}{x}$ is a distribution, as a product of infinite differentiable function and a distribution, for all $a>0$. So, it makes sense to ask what is $\lim_{a\to +\infty} e^{ax}P\frac{1}{x}$ and it is not existing. So, there is an array of distributions without a limit.